# How do I get cURL code to compile on Windows 10?

Tags: javascript, curl

I am following an online tutorial about creating a javascript-based server/client environment, and to test a POST method, the author gave a block of cURL code to run. When I try to run it, however, I get errors.

I have done some research, and I'm fairly sure that the provided code is for a Linux environment, but I'm operating on Windows 10. I tried changing the `\` characters to `^` but I'm still getting errors. I have used both the cmd prompt and PowerShell.

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:3000/signup \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "email": "test5@test.com",
    "password": "1234",
    "name": "test5"
}'
```

I expected the code to post data to my database, but instead I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\ricks>curl -X POST \
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \

C:\Users\ricks>  http://localhost:3000/signup \
'http:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\ricks>  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
'-H' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\ricks>  -d '{
'-d' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\ricks>"email": "test5@test.com",
'"email":' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\ricks>"password": "1234",
'"password":' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\ricks>"name": "test5"
'"name":' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: I've never been able to do POST data in `curl` from a DOS prompt either. But I've had good luck running `curl` from inside an `sh` implementation on windows.

Comment: @David784 would I need to install a Linux environment on my computer to do that?

Comment: [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) is fairly easy to install and it comes in handy to test Unix style commands like this one.

Comment: I use the tools included with [GIT for windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win), since I already have it installed. But there are a lot of options out there. I also understand Microsoft now has something called [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), although I've never used it. (I only use windows at work...all linux at home)

Comment: @David784 Since you mentioned that you've attempted and failed (like me) to POST data through a DOS prompt, I thought I'd let you know that I cracked the code (no pun intended). See my answer for a way to get cURL working in a local Windows environment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While all of the answers provided would undoubtedly lead to me being able to run the cURL code I posted above, I found a workaround using only the Windows cmd prompt.

First, I compiled the code in a single line rather than multiple. Second, I discovered that the compile errors came primarily from un-escaped `"` characters. In the end, the following code worked correctly and POSTed data to my database!

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/signup -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"email\" : \"test4@test.com\", \"password\" : \"1234\",  \"name\": \"test5\" }"
```

While this is likely not the most sustainable approach, it was a good learning moment for me and it might help those looking to utilize a one-time cURL execution without downloading anything extra to their system.

Answer (score 0):

first download & install [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com), and make sure to install the `gcc-core` and `g++` and `make` and `autoconf` and `automake` and `git` and `libtool` and `m4` packages during package selection (there may be more required, if you get a compile-error, i can probably deduce the missing package by your complication error, let me know.),

and i guess you want your curl installation to support TLS/HTTPS? (almost all websites require httpS these days) in which case, you gotta start by compiling openssl,

(replace `1_1_1c` with the latest openssl stable release... it is 1.1.1c as of writing.)

```
git clone -b 'OpenSSL_1_1_1c' --single-branch --depth 1 https://github.com/openssl/openssl
cd openssl
./config no-shared
make -j $(nproc)
```

(the last step may take a while) but openSSL's build script does not create a lib folder, but curl's build script expect the lib files to be in a lib folder inside the openssl folder, so after that, run

```
mkdir lib
cp *.a lib;
```

after openssl is compiled, `cd ..` out of there, it's time to make curl,

(replace `7_65_3` with whatever the latest stable curl release is. as of writing, it is `7.65.3`)

```
git clone -b 'curl-7_65_3' --single-branch --depth 1 https://github.com/curl/curl.git
cd curl
./buildconf
LDFLAGS="-static" ./configure --with-ssl=$(realpath ../openssl) --disable-shared  --enable-static
make -j $(nproc)
```

(if you wonder why i used realpath: there appears to be a bug in curl's buildscript that makes it fail if you supply a relative path, so an absolute path is required, it seems. if you wonder why i made a static build aka --disable-shared --enable-static, you may have a different libopenssl library in your $PATH, so to avoid a variation of [DLL Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell), a static build is safer.)

and finally you have your own curl build in the relative path `./src/curl` after make has finished, which you can run with:

```
./src/curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:3000/signup \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "email": "test5@test.com",
    "password": "1234",
    "name": "test5"
}'
```

in a cygwin terminal. (which has the same syntax as linux terminals)

........... alternatively, you can just install the `curl` package from cygwin, and use cygwin's pre-compiled curl, but since you asked specifically how to COMPILE curl, there's your answer. i recommend you avoid the hassle and just install cygwin's pre-compiled curl.

Comment: I wish I could give you +5 for your thoughtful and thorough answer. As I posted in my own answer, I was able to compile the code in a local Windows environment by simply escaping the ```"``` characters. I didn't, however, want to move on from this problem without acknowledging the effort you put in, so thank you!

Comment: @RickSchimka that's called `running` or `executing` curl, not `compiling` ^^ - check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler

Answer (score 0):

> I tried changing the \ characters to ^ but I'm still getting errors

This is not even the start of the problems in migrating the code. There are compiled versions available on [application's home site](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win64) for Windows 32 and 64 bit with and without Cygwin already available.

Comment: if he installs a pre-compiled version of curl, that won't solve the cmd shell syntax errors, but if he installs Cygwin, he can trivially get both curl and solve the syntax error at the same time :P (Cygwin's terminal has the bash syntax, and the installer has curl as an optional component... but Cygwin also makes it easy-ish to compile curl from scratch, if he really wants. and he really did ask how to *compile* curl, but i don't see why he'd actually want to do that.)

Comment: Only if the errors you are refer to are because he is trying to run a POSIX shell script via cmd or powershell. If the OP doesn't know the differenence between these, then he/show does not have the skills to port the source code.

Comment: @hanshenrik as it turns out, my biggest syntax enemy was just un-escaped ```"``` characters! I posted an answer above that shows how to compile the cURL code locally in a Windows environment!